# No way of getting the length/size/count of an element of type DbSett?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

The [documentation for `DbSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx) appears not to have any way of returning the number of elements in a `DbSet`. Perhaps I'm wrong about that. In any case, let me explain my situation:

I have a class `Score` modeling rows of a table in my database

```
public partial class Score
{
    public Score()
    {
        GameLogs = new HashSet<GameLog>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column("score")]
    public int score1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public DateTime playdate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GameLog> GameLogs { get; set; }
}
```

and the model of the table is of type `DbSet<Score>` and I'm trying to create a method that returns the top 5 rows ordered by `score1`, or, if the database has fewer than 5 rows, return all the rows ordered by `score1`.

What I have is

```
    public DbSet<Score> getTopFiveOrFewerScores ( )
    {
        return (
                  from s in SD.Scores
                  orderby s.score1 descending
                  select s
                ).Take(Math.Min(SD.Scores.length, 5));
    }
```

The main problem is that I'm putting `length` there as a placeholder since there apparently isn't a `length` or equivalent property on a `DbSet`. Another problem is that Visual Studio is saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

on the Take statement.

Any guidance here?

Answer (score 0):

Use Take (5); It will take a MAXIMUM of 5 elements or less if not even 5 are available.

In  the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx)  we can read: " Take enumerates source and yields elements until count elements have been yielded orsource contains no more elements. ".